Is there a way to configure GridCoverageWriter to write (Band data type) byte instead of float16
I would like to store my GridCoverage2d as a Tiff-file with band type "byte", but I can't find how to configure the writer for that.
This is how far I got:
            final GeoTiffFormat format2 = new GeoTiffFormat();
            final GeoTiffWriteParams wp = new GeoTiffWriteParams();
            wp.setCompressionMode(GeoTiffWriteParams.MODE_EXPLICIT);
            wp.setCompressionType("LZW");
            final ParameterValueGroup params = format.getWriteParameters();
            params.parameter(AbstractGridFormat.GEOTOOLS_WRITE_PARAMS.getName().toString()).setValue(wp);
            GridCoverageWriter writer = null;
            if (grdCov != null) {
                final File writeFile = new File(txtOutputName.getText());
                writer = format2.getWriter(writeFile);
                writer.write(grdCov, (GeneralParameterValue[]) params.values().toArray(new GeneralParameterValue[1]));
            }
            writer.dispose();


All I can suggest is looking at ImageTypeSpecifier which seems to have a dataType parameter. and looks like you can pass it to a GeoTiffMetaDataWriter
